# Failing to read file loaded with ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
void bot_manager_item::create_games()
{
    games.clear();
    std::ifstream paths_in("C:\\Users\\bill hank\\Documents\\bot_plugins\\directory_listing.txt", std::ios::in);
    while (paths_in.good())
    {
        send_message("The path was good.");
        char q[5000];
        paths_in.getline(q, 5000);
        send_message(q);
        games.push_back(qanda(q));
    }
    paths_in.close();
}
```

The file I'm loading exists, what else might be wrong? paths_in.good keeps failing.

Edit: I figured it out. Wow am I annoyed by the answer to this. Basically Windows lets you say whether you want to show file extensions or not. This windows installation is set to say that the extension shouldn't be shown. So when I'm checking the file again and again I'm seeing: directory.txt and thinking that this means that everything is fine with the directory when in reality the filename was directory.txt.txt

Comment: BTW: `std::getline` function allows you to read from a stream to a `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Kos =). I'm on a really tight deadline or I would refactor my code =)

Answer (score 3):

If `paths_in.good()` keeps failing then it means that some of the stream error flags are set (`badbit`, `eofbit` or `failbit`).

- `eofbit` - end of file was reached
- `badbit` - error with the stream buffer such as memory shortage or an exception inside the stream buffer is cast
- `failbit` - some other error beside eof was reached

In order to find out what happened, you need to check which errorbit is set first, and then find out more about the specific error, and what can cause it.

Comment: failbit was the one that came up.

Comment: Anything else you can tell me knowing that it is failbit that is set?

Comment: I think this is failing because it cannot open the file, and it could be down to the directory name, specifically `bill hank`, not sure how that is being interpreted. Maybe try escaping the space?

Comment: @Josh could the failure also be due to admin privileges? Try moving the file to another directory w/o any space as Nim suggest or even a dummy file with a different name. Does the failbit still get set in that case?

Comment: Yea it does, I moved it to the C:\\ folder and it still got the failbit.

Comment: Are you opening the same file in your program before the create games method, or is this code the only one that opens that file? Can you also add the line cout << strerror(errno) << endl; after the call to open the file. if one is lucky, depending on platform, some more information will be printed out.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, does this code output the contents of the file correctly? If this code works, then the problem is something else. If this code doesn't work, then that likely means that the file either isn't where you specified, or you don't have read permissions on it.

```
void bot_manager_item::create_games() {
    std::ifstream paths_in("C:\\Users\\bill hank\\Documents\\bot_plugins\\directory_listing.txt");

    char q[5000];
    while (paths_in.getline(q, 5000)) {
        std::cout << q << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This code does a few minor things differently.

1. `std::ios::in` doesn't need to be explicitly specified for `std::ifstream`.
2. it doesn't use is_good, while that should be fine, you can just treat the `std::ifstream` as a bool which will be `true` when it is in a good state.
3. getline() returns a reference to the stream it operated on, so you can just put that whole line in the condition.
4. cosmetic, but no need to explicitly close the `ifstream` if it is about to go out of scope.