# Loading file in C++, failbit is set and I can't figure out why

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failing to read file loaded with ifstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531213/failing-to-read-file-loaded-with-ifstream)

The output of the following file is: 00100.
This indicates to me that failbit is set. The problem is I can't figure out why it is set. Anyone have some insight to share?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

    std::ifstream paths_in("C:\\Users\\bill hank\\AppData\\bot_plugins\\directory_listing.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::cout << paths_in.good();
    std::cout << paths_in.is_open();
    std::cout << paths_in.fail();
    std::cout << paths_in.eof();
    std::cout << paths_in.bad();
    while (paths_in.good())
    {
        char q[5000];
        paths_in.getline(q, 5000);
        std::cout << q;
    }
    paths_in.close();
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I figured it out. Wow am I annoyed by the answer to this. Basically Windows lets you say whether you want to show file extensions or not. This windows installation is set to say that the extension shouldn't be shown. So when I'm checking the file again and again I'm seeing: directory.txt and thinking that this means that everything is fine with the directory when in reality the filename was directory.txt.txt

Comment: Edit your current question instead of asking another question with the same code.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, there is nothing wrong in your code, so there *must* be something wrong in your environment :

- Have you checked the file location ?
- Are you sure you actually have the permission to read the file ?
- Is the file already opened in exclusive mode by another process (you could probably check this using [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) for example) ?

Comment: I've quadruple checked the file location. Than I checked it again ten more times. Not sure about permission and process exclusivity though, looking into those now.

Comment: I checked a hundred freaking times and saw "directory_listing.txt" each time. I didn't realize that in reality Windows was set to hide file extensions. What was really there was "directory_listing.txt.txt" Very annoying little bug. Second time this week that something like this has bit me.

Comment: @Joshua: haha nice :) I would have never thought about this

Answer (score 0):

Write a call to CreateFile and see what you get for an error code.